# Pywintauto findbestmatch alternative

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am working with `Pywinauto` to automate a `Desktop Application`.

At one point there could be a popup window. With `findbestmatch` I want to check if the popup is available. The name of the popup window is the same as of the normal window.

Is there an alternative for `findbestmatch` or is it the best option?

Comment: What do you mean saying `findbestmatch`? Direct usage of this module or using `best_match` names for window specification? It could be helpful to provide any code sample with what you're trying.

Comment: `best_match` names is not the only way. Single or few properties usage is possible with exact matching. BTW, it works faster than `best_match` names usually. Just post your code and I can show how to re-write it more properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pywinauto function called `popup_window()` which could be a good starting point for you. See  [link](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html?highlight=popup#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper.popup_window)

Its listed under [pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html?highlight=popup#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper.popup_window), which provides basic wrapping of windows controls. It will return the handle/id of any open popups or a reference to self if no popups exist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it out